# Xcode - how to add a flag which can be checked in a header file?

Tags: ios, xcode, settings, flags

I have a `header file` with many `constants` set for my project.
I would like to run a certain part of my code `depending on the target I've chosen`.
I know how one way to do this is by using NSBundle's `infoDictionary` method. However, I would like to use only .h file here for all my constants.

Currently I am using `DEBUG` flag and running my code by checking this flag as such:

```
#if DEBUG
...
#else
...
#endif
```

I would like to be able to add my own flag(s) in my targets and check for those in header file, rather than rely on DEBUG flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the flags to the Preprocessor Macros in build settings for the target.

[image]